# How to select dates from dual, but with joined data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I got an SQL problem I'm not capable to solve.

First of all, an SQL fiddle with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe7b07/2

As you see, I fill the table with some dates, which are bound to some ID. Those dates are day by day. So for this example, we'd have something like this, if we only look at January:

[image: I should have been an painter, not database admin]

The timelines spanning from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-31, the blocks are the dates in the database. So this would be the simple `SELECT * FROM days` output.

What I now want is to fill in some days to this output. These would span from `timeline_begin` to `MIN(date_from)`; and from `MAX(date_from)` to `timeline_end`.

I'll mark these red in the following picture:

[image]

The orange span is not necessary to be added, too, but if your solution would do that too, that would be also ok.

Ok, so far so good.

For this I created the `SELECT * FROM minmax`, which will select the `MIN(date_from)` and `MAX(date_from)` for every `id_othertable`. Still no magic involved.

What I struggle is now creating those days for every `id_othertable`, while also joining the data they have on them (in this fiddle, it's just the `some_info` field).

I tried to write this in the `SELECT * FROM days_before` query, but I just can't get it to work. I read about the magical function `CONNECT BY`, which will on its own create dates line by line, but I can't get to join my data from the former table. Every time I join the info, I only get *one* line per `id_othertable`, not all those dates I need.

So the ideal solution I'm looking for would be to have three select queries:

1. `SELECT * FROM days` which select dates out of the database
2. `SELECT * FROM days_before` which will show the dates before `MIN(date_from)` of query 1
3. `SELECT * FROM days_after` for dates after `MAX(date_from)` of query 1

And in the end I'd `UNION` those three queries to have them all combined.

I hope I could explain my problem good enough. If you need any information or further explaining, please don't hesitate to ask.

---

EDIT 1: I created a pastebin with some example data: https://pastebin.com/jskrStpZ

Bear in mind that only the first query has actual information from the database, the other two have created data. Also, this example output only has data for `id_othertable = 1`, so the actual query should also have the information for `id_othertable = 2, 3`.

EDIT 2: just for clarification, the field `date_to` is just a simple `date_from + 1 day`.

Comment: Can you post a table with your expected result? I might just be too tired to understand what exactly you mean.

Comment: of course! I edited it into the post, I hope this is helpful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the dates per `id` that are not in the database then you can use the `LEAD` analytic function:

```sql
WITH dates ( id, date_from, date_to ) AS (
  SELECT id_othertable,
         DATE '2020-01-01',
         MIN( date_from )
  FROM   some_dates
  WHERE  date_to > DATE '2020-01-01'
  AND    date_from < ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2020-01-01', 1 )
  GROUP BY id_othertable
UNION ALL
  SELECT id_othertable,
         date_to,
         LEAD( date_from, 1, ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2020-01-01', 1 ) )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY id_othertable ORDER BY date_from )
  FROM   some_dates
  WHERE  date_to > DATE '2020-01-01'
  AND    date_from < ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2020-01-01', 1 )
)
SELECT id,
       date_from,
       date_to
FROM   dates
WHERE  date_from < date_to
ORDER BY id, date_from;
```

so for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_dates ( id_othertable, date_from, date_to, some_info ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-05', DATE '2020-01-06', 'hello1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-06', DATE '2020-01-07', 'hello2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-07', DATE '2020-01-08', 'hello3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-10', DATE '2020-01-13', 'hello4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-01-10', DATE '2020-01-13', 'my'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-01-20', DATE '2020-01-23', 'friend' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2019-12-31', DATE '2020-01-05', 'before' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2020-01-30', DATE '2020-02-02', 'after'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2019-12-31', DATE '2020-01-10', 'only_before' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, DATE '2020-01-15', DATE '2020-02-01', 'only_after'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, DATE '2019-12-31', DATE '2020-02-01', 'exlude_all'  FROM DUAL;
```

this outputs:

> ```
> ID | DATE_FROM  | DATE_TO   
> -: | :--------- | :---------
>  1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05
>  1 | 2020-01-08 | 2020-01-10
>  1 | 2020-01-13 | 2020-02-01
>  2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10
>  2 | 2020-01-13 | 2020-02-01
>  3 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-20
>  3 | 2020-01-23 | 2020-02-01
>  4 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-30
>  5 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-02-01
>  6 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31528e49a780c5a87e1453d919d7d80e)*

If you want the days before then filter on:

```
WHERE day_from = DATE '2020-01-01'
```

and, similarly, if you want the days after then filter on:

```
WHERE day_to = ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2020-01-01', 1 )
```

If you want to specify the start date and number of months duration then use named bind parameters:

```sql
WITH dates ( id, date_from, date_to ) AS (
  SELECT id_othertable,
         :start_date,
         MIN( date_from )
  FROM   some_dates
  WHERE  date_to > :start_date
  AND    date_from < ADD_MONTHS( :start_date, :number_months )
  GROUP BY id_othertable
UNION ALL
  SELECT id_othertable,
         date_to,
         LEAD( date_from, 1, ADD_MONTHS( :start_date, :number_months ) )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY id_othertable ORDER BY date_from )
  FROM   some_dates
  WHERE  date_to > :start_date
  AND    date_from < ADD_MONTHS( :start_date, :number_months )
)
SELECT id,
       date_from,
       date_to
FROM   dates
WHERE  date_from < date_to
ORDER BY id, date_from;
```

Comment: Nice one. Thought to modify another solution where I added different timeframes to existing data. Like CD HI to BC IJ + AB to ABCD + DEF to E +E to DEF + DEF to CD FG. But didn't find my code

Comment: hey @MT0, this is so promising! I'm working with it now for a few days and it's awesome! added two more ID fields, which I added to the GROUP/PARTITION BY and it does exactly what I want. My problem now is, that I'm working with TIMESTAMP in the database, not DATEs. I'm even ok to only have DATE as the result, but I struggle to get the LEAD function working with my timestamps out of the DB. would you have any guess on where I should start editing this query?

Comment: @Trollwut It should just work without any modification [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=df888bfa4bfc090517ba3e3a52452ffa). If it is not working then you'll need to generate a [MRE] that can replicate the problem as it is working for me and I don't know what changes you have made and how that will affect the results. If it is a new problem then you should ask a new question (rather than editing this one) and you can always @ mention me on this answer with a link to the new question and I'll try to look at it.

Comment: thanks, this is very generous of you! oof, does work with timestamps, too. so it seems to be something from my DB that won't do it. I'm currently working on said minimal sample, just give me a second.

Comment: Ok Mr. @Mt0, I'M FUCKEN STUPID. That is now a proven fact. This is my minimal case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98e34d/1 and see there: it doesn't consolidate these single days. That's what I've been trying to do since hours. Solution? I'm so stupid that I forgot the last "where date_from < date_to". And BOOM! it works... so now MT0, I really have to thank you, you gave me a wonderful exact solution to my problem. You helped me very much!

Comment: @Trollwut Your welcome. If this or any other answer has solved your problem then you can mark it as your preferred solution with the check mark below the voting buttons (to the left of the answer) as that will let other people know which solution worked for you.

Comment: of course! sorry, went with joy into lunch break :D you really earned that mark, very nice, performant and manageable solution!

Answer (score 4):

If you have denormalised date it's quite simple:

```
with bas as (
    select 1 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'hello' some_info from dual
    union all select 1 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'hello' some_info from dual
    union all select 1 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'hello' some_info from dual
    union all select 1 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'hello' some_info from dual
    union all select 1 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'hello' some_info from dual
    union all select 1 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'hello' some_info from dual
    union all select 2 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'my' some_info from dual
    union all select 2 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'my' some_info from dual
    union all select 2 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'my' some_info from dual
    union all select 3 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'friend' some_info from dual
    union all select 3 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'friend' some_info from dual
    union all select 3 id_other_table, to_date('2020-01-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2020-01-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_to, 'friend' some_info from dual)
, ad as (select trunc(sysdate,'YYYY') -1 + level all_dates from dual connect by level <= 31)
select distinct some_info,all_dates from bas,ad where (some_info,all_dates) not in (select some_info,date_from from bas)
```

If you have longer date ranges or mind of the time the query needs another solution is helpful. But that is harder to debug. Because it's quite hard to get the orange time slot

Comment: that looks like a promising approach. but the date ranges to be created can differ. It might be just a month like here, but could also be a year. And it will be a ton of different `id_other_table`, so performance is crucial.

Comment: the orange span is *not* necessary. if a solution would include it, that would be good too, but the red ones are those I really need :)

Answer (score 2):

Select whole range using `connect by` generator. Join your table partitioned by id.

```
select date_from, nvl(date_to, date_from +1) date_to, id_othertable, some_info
  from (
    select date '2020-01-01' + level - 1 as date_from 
      from dual 
      connect by level <= date '2020-01-31' - date '2020-01-01' ) gen 
  natural left join some_dates partition by (id_othertable)
```

**<sup>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe7b07/32)</sup>**

Comment: that looks amazingly good! now when I look e.g. only on `id_othertable = 1`, I see that the new added rows have `some_info = (null)`. Is there an easy way to join the same data here as the "source id_othertable=1"?

Comment: Yes, add `some_info` to `partition by`: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe7b07/42). If there will be several `info` values data will be multiplicated. If you need other solutions in these case please explain logic, it can be last value, min, max etc.

Comment: hey stibbons, thanks that worked! I'm aware that I can only PARTITION data which is the same in any other connected row. Now my last problem: In my former select, I cuold have something like `date_how_far_into_past`. Is there *any* way to get this date into the subselect of the natural join?

Comment: I edited your last fiddle and inserted a comment of which I meant: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f7a39/3